# pip install - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, windows, permissions, pip, anaconda

## Environment

- Windows 8.1
- Python 3.5
- Anaconda

## Issue

When I do `pip install sklearn --upgrade`, I got the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 322, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "d:\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'd:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils\\m
urmurhash.cp35-win_amd64.pyd'
```

The command prompt is run as an Administrator, so I have the permission.

What should I do? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: pip fails miserably at replacing loaded EXEs and DLLs (a PYD is a DLL). Such files can't be deleted or overwritten, but they can be renamed to a temp directory on the same disk volume to get them out of the way. pip doesn't even try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed its dependencies like **numpy** and **scipy**? Check it out and then we will proceed further.

Final Solution:
 try `conda` like `conda install scikit-learn=_version_`

Comment: I already have them. But when I try to upgrade them, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Hmm Why don't you try `conda` there? like `conda install scikit-learn=_version_` @dixhom

Comment: Okay, I am updating my answer with this solution. Don't forget to up vote I want more reputations u know? ;) @dixhom

Comment: In my particular case, it was a different package. I changed the permission of the file but was not helpful. In the end, I just deleted the file (basically moved it to another location as a backup). On running the command again, it ran and the package also got restored by pip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this exact problem on my Windows 10 pc with Anaconda Python 3.6 installed:

- open an Anaconda prompt window as administrator
- pip uninstall kivy
- pip install kivy
- pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2