# PyQt5 pip installation error 13. Permission denied

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install PyQt5 with the command `pip install PyQt5`

but I get an error instead.

I use Python 3.5, windows 10.

error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install PyQt5

Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.7-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting sip (from PyQt5)
  Using cached sip-4.18.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: sip, PyQt5
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 324, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\sip.pyd'
```

Comment: Are you logged in as Administrator user on the machine?  Try to run cmd prompt as administrator see if that helps

Comment: @Yan I use administrator

Comment: Have you seen this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809739/pip-install-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied

Comment: Yes using conda did not solve it.

Answer (score 25):

With different Windows (8.2) and different PyQt (4-4) I had the same problem.

What worked for me was:
run task manager and see if there are any Python tasks running. If there are (there were for me) kill them, as they (probably) lock the sip.pyd file. Then run  `pip install` again ("successfully installed" in my case).

Comment: Works perfect on Win7 with Python 3.6

Comment: Great, it also worked for PyQt4 / Python 2.7 on Windows for me.

Comment: Works with Windows 10 and WinPython 3.5. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Python3.6 Win10 x64 with Anaconda.
Same problem
as @user6904670 said,

> kill running python.exe

and 
**Close Anaconda.exe and other related process**

Answer (score 1):

Run the cmd window as administrator (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Syntax is not right for PyQt5 because PyQt5 is not compatible with pip, So
you have to use pip3.
use this command

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

Read this article for more information official http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html

Comment: Try to format command line input as code, it will show more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python 3.x was installed to its preferred (default) location C:\ **Program Files** \Pyton3x and if you are running your code not with elevated privileges in OS (not as administrator), then consider giving all user permissions to Python installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you have Anaconda install try
conda navigator and pip